# 403 error on soap incoming message but not from postman

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, postman, salesforce

I have a very strange error, and frankly I don't have any clue what's causing it. I'm attempting to set up outbound messages for a salesforce account (which send SOAP messages) and I'm running a Ubuntu server through Digital ocean. I've installed and configured Nginx. Now, every message that salesforce attempts to send fails out with a 403 error which points me to the server and Nginx. But when I tail the logs (both regular and access) I don't see any indication that the post is even making it to the server. I have a firewall UFW, but it shouldn't be blocking it from making it to Nginx and shouldn't be sending a 403. And we use cloudflare, but I don't have any inbound rules set up that should be blocking this. The weirdest part is that I can send a postman post request and it works just fine. I see the logs show up and everything. Any ideas here?